# How to read xlsx file and store it in database in low memory using node.js?

Tags: node.js, event-handling, extract, xlsx, readable

I have used many **third-party** npm. But I can't pause and resume it. I need to **pause** the stream while storing data in Mongodb and **resume** it. I have used **fs.createReadStream()**. while using stream I got only arrayBuffer type data so I can't convert or store it in the database. Then I used third-party npm to extract data from xlsx. Here I got data in JSON format but I can't pause and resume in those npm packages. Please help me to resolve it. Code must use **low memory**.

```
// I have used fs.createReadStream(). But I can't get in proper format
const fs = require("fs");

const stream = fs.createReadStream("demo.xlsx");
stream.on("data", (data) => {
  stream.pause();

  console.log(data);
  // I got data in arrabuffer format I can't get readable format like json, array ets,.
  // database store
  // after data stored in db i need to resume it

  stream.resume();
});

// and I used xlsx-extract npm but I can't pause and resume while data storing
var XLSX = require('xlsx-extract').XLSX;
new XLSX().extract('path/to/file.xlsx', {sheet_id:1})
        .on('sheet', function (sheet) {
            console.log('sheet',sheet);
        })
        .on('row', function (row) {
            // want to pause it
            console.log('row', row);
            // want to resume it
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.error('error', err);
        })
        .on('end', function (err) {
            console.log('eof');
        });
```